# RemoteView background tranparency

Tags: android, android-widget

I've been trying to use `remoteView.setFloat(R.id.remote_background, "setAlpha", (float) 0.7);` to set background transparency/alpha, but I'm getting "Error loading widget". I've read that you can set transparency by adding a hex value in front of a color. But since I'm getting the color from ColorPicker and it's an integer value (example: -13890612), I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hex notation to see the color as it is in format RRGGBB, so your `-13890612` should be rather peeked as `2C0BCC` which makes more sense as you can easily say what are values of each components of the color. And to add alpha channel (which is value from 0 - (full transparent) to 0xff (full opaque)), just `OR` the right value with your color and use. I.e. to make it semi transparent OR 0x80:

```
int rgb  = 0x2C0BCC;
int argb = 0x80000000 | rgb;
```

Answer (score 0):

USe `setInt(R.id.remote_background, "setBackgroundColor", colorInt);` instead.